# how can i popup picture in php?

Tags: javascript, html, css

when picture viewed ,when me click on it picture will display as pop up, and back screen will be light black?

Comment: This is not php-related at all btw. PHP is a server-side language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this site: http://ajaxian.com/archives/lightboxjs-easy-image-overlays-with-javascript

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't be done with PHP alone, since you don't want to reload your page every time you click on an image. Google for lightbox and use an appropriate JavaScript library for client side effects :)

Answer (score 1):

use jquery there are many plugins to do it http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/ for example

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Lightbox](http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox/) or [Lightbox2](http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/)

Comment: it is not that hard to provide a link and not be snarky about it.  Many answers like yours (RTMF, LMGTFU, etc.) are just deleted.